# How to properly save and retrieve file on android

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to make my program save it's current state on internal memory so i can retrieve it when it loads up next time.
But it seems like i can't get it to work, my app keeps crashing on boot.

```
private File statoContatori = new File(getFilesDir(), "statoContatori");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inizializeCounters();
}

private void inizializeCounters() {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(statoContatori);
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            String idContatore = in.next();
            String nomeContatore = in.next();
            String valore = in.next();
            if (idContatore.equals("contatore_1"))
            {
                initializeContatore(R.id.contatore_1_label, R.id.contatore_1, nomeContatore, valore);
            }
            else if (idContatore.equals("contatore_2"))
            {
                initializeContatore(R.id.contatore_2_label, R.id.contatore_2, nomeContatore, valore);
                    //There are a couple more IFs in here...
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        creaFileStatoContatori();
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private void creaFileStatoContatori() {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(statoContatori);
        out.println("contatore_1\tcontatore_1\t0");
        out.println("contatore_2\tcontatore_2\t0");
        out.println("contatore_3\tcontatore_3\t0");
        out.println("contatore_4\tcontatore_4\t0");
        out.println("contatore_5\tcontatore_5\t0");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        out.close();
    }
    inizializeCounters();
}
```

So basically what i'm trying to do is:
If the file is present -> load the file
If the file is not present -> create the file with standard configs -> load the file
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace of your crash on boot.

Comment: Can you tell me how do i do that from eclipse please?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#logcat

Comment: What is statoContatori ? Probablly it is null in _in = new Scanner(statoContatori);_ and throws a NPE.

Comment: statoContatori is a private field, i forgot to add it in this question, but it was declared and is not null.

Comment: From logCat i can see i have an "error opening trace file: no such file or directory"
But the only piece of code throwing such an exception is where i create the printwriter in which case i am CREATING the new file, am i wrong?

Comment: What is getFilesDir() ?

Comment: default method of Android Context class:
Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files of your app are stored.